# i need to find records which have max categories

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, categories

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | eat,drink |
| 2 | drink,cup |
| 3 | eat,take |
| 4 | tea,eat |

i need to order records which have max number of category repeated by category column, ex- eat are repeated 3 times then it is comes first order and then drink comes then tea or cup comes..
thanks in advance..

Comment: You should fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a delimited string is not the SQL way to store data.

Comment: You will find that [many queries become hard to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574) when you store comma-separated lists like this. They will be easier if you store categories as a separate table, one row per category.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff  but we can not change the flow on mid of project , do you have solution for  above flow.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon suggested data model should be changed to get most out of RDBMS. But what you are looking for can be achieved through below query:

```
select category,count(*) category_count from(
select t.id, j.category 
from tablename t
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(t.category ), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (category  varchar(50) path '$')
) j
)t
group by category
order by count(*) desc;
```

**Output:**

[image]